Telegram bot in Spring Boot 3
I wanted to use  org.telegramtelegrambots-spring-boot-starter6.9.7.1  in Spring Boot 3.3.4 version, but it didn't support telegrambot in any version, What do I have to do to fix it?
I expect to initialize any version of telegrambot in Spring Boot 3.

No that's an unrealistic expectation, you need to use a version that matches. You can't just expect to be able to use any version you want. Shockingly, there is upgrade documentation. https://rubenlagus.github.io/TelegramBotsDocumentation/how-to-update-7.html .

There's another way that can be considered or just more information for your reference.
You can download the source code from the official repository: https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots
And then build the jar files locally and add them back to your maven project.
The latest version 7.10.0 is compatible with Spring boot 3.2.3
Notice that the telegrambots-spring-boot-starter is gone but became telegrambots-springboot-longpolling-starter and telegrambots-springboot-webhook-starter.
